# How to put a javascript link in a python script

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, hyperlink

Im trying to make a python script open up a javascript link but it doesnt seem to work and it just gives me a invalid syntax because of the : symbol along with a few other symbols here is the line that is causing me issues

`webbrowser.open('Javascript:$.get('//example/l/example/example.js')'), new=0, autoraise=True)`

Comment: since python doesn't include a javascript engine, it can't run javascript

Comment: @Bravo That might be my issue I was assuming when I would webbrowser open it the webbrowser would take control and run it